# Not able access files from iCloud drive

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

I have to integrate the simple functionality  for saving and retrieving the file(eg. .text , .pdf etc) in iCloud drive and also i want to access all the file which are available in iCloud drive. Prerequisites are already done as - 
1) AppId with iCloud enabled.
2) from capabilities also added the key-value storage, iCloud document and iCloud kit are already checked.

But when I want to access the files through
 NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManagerdefaultManager]URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

it returns me the url 
 Cloud access at file:///Users/ankitsharma/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ECD8EDE2-9364-432F-8832-44ED5B5813BE/data/Library/Mobile%20Documents/NameofMyAppcontainer/

**How i can download all the files that are available in iCloud drive and show to the user so that he can send that file to another user?**

Comment: Go to google and search for the term "accessing icloud drive ios swift tutorial" and the first link you will find has the answer. https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/icloud-drive-documents-1a46b5706fe1#.krhe3bd0i so does the second https://www.raywenderlich.com/83116/beginning-cloudkit-tutorial and the third http://www.appcoda.com/cloudkit-introduction-tutorial/ and the one after that too http://www.appcoda.com/icloud-programming-ios-intro-tutorial/. Do you get the picture

Comment: @user3069232 I have gone through [link] (raywenderlich.com/83116/beginning-cloudkit-tutorial)  but still i am not getting the documents from my iCloud drive. I have modified the already existing app ID for iCloud. Is their any permission left for to do so.